# make a string a new instant of a class in C#

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem I can not solve. and I hope someone can.

// I got Table saved in M.SQL server as in Picture

[image]

```html
// Code

DB_Context MYDB = new DB_Context();
var ALL = MYDB.select(x => x );

I want to instantiate every string ( i.Position) as a new instant name of class ARTICLE.like the followings 

 foreach ( var i in ALL)
{
ARTICLE "i.Position" = new ARTICLE();
"i.Name".A_STOCK = i.Stock ;
}

// The Class
public Class ARTICLE
{
public int A_STOCK { get; set;}

}

// later I want to recall it to get its A_STOCK value , for example 

int k1 = A1.A_STOCK ;
int k2 = A2.A_STOCK ;
```

// 
In short , I want to retrieve all strings in Position Column and convert every string of them into a a new instant of class (ARTICLE) carries then instant name ...

Thank you very much ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy, just do it in your select using [object initialization syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer).

```
DB_Context MYDB = new DB_Context();
var ALL = MYDB.select(x => { new ARTICLE { A_STOCK = x.Stock};  );
```

After making this change, `ALL` will contain a list of ARTICLE objects instead of a list of strings.

Comment: thank you for the Answer. But still the solution without the instances ( A1 , A2 ,A3 ... ). In fact, I want to make about 1600 instances , and every instance has different attributes ( like NAME, Model, Version. .. etc).

Comment: The instances are there; they are contained inside of `ALL`. You can convert to an array, list, or whatever you want.  Are you suggesting that you want one variable, with its own symbol, for each and every instance?  No arrays?  That would be insane design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<T>`:

```
var articles = new List<ARTICLE>();
foreach(var i in ALL)
    articles.Add(new ARTICLE() { A_STOCK = i.Stock });

var k1 = articles[0].A_STOCK;
var k2 = articles[1].A_STOCK;
///etc...
```

Btw, so many things wrong with your style.... Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

Comment: thanks for Answer and Infos. but still the answer misses to Instances themselves ( i.e A1, A2, A3 ... etc)